# How to make change in cells of GridView without touching them? Android java

Tags: java, android, android-adapter, android-gridview

I have a `gridview` with cell value of either 1 or 0. If the value is 1 i want background change without clicking on any cell, just by loading activity.

Comment: Write some code please.

Comment: its very simple, set value 1 or 0 for each adapter item when you fill your adapter with your data and on that basis you can set background color of each cell (grid item) in your adapter class.

Comment: Can you please explain with example.

Comment: Obviously you may be using adapter view so you just called notifyDataSetChanged() to see changes

Comment: Dude i am still not getting, how can i use notifyDataSetChanged() for changing background colour without single click on any cell. Basically i have this activity which load with grid view. Grid view contain a array adapter so it set value in cell either 1 or 0. I want code which change the background colour if cell value is 1, without any single click on screen.

Comment: I want an if condition which will check values of every cell in grid view, and if cell value is 1 it changes it's background colour, without any type of click event. Just by loading the activity.